# How do I call chroot from within Java?

Tags: java, unix, filesystems, system-calls, chroot

I'm trying to implement my own basic shell in Java. One of the things I want to do is that when a user logs in, the  `<shell-path>/<username>/` directory gets "mounted" (it's on the same file system, but it essentially boots the system). I know in C, there is the `chroot` system call to set up a sub-environment, but I can't find the equivalent in Java. Is there one/how do I still access the other directories?

Comment: You'd have to use JNI, or something built on JNI.  And then, after you call `chroot()`, it's quite likely your JVM will fail if it ever tries to locate something like another jar file or the JRE's trust store.